# html5 nav height style

Tags: css, html

Html:

```
<body>
        <div>
            <header>
            HTML5
            </header>           
            <nav>
             <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Login</a></li>

             </ul>

            </nav>
            <p id="navclear" />
```

css:

```
/*page*/
body{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height:auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}



/*navigation*/
nav{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    height:auto;
}
nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    !margin-top:0;


}


nav li a{
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    display: block;
    padding-right:5px;
    width:75px;
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    color:#66777F;
    !line-height: .5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:Cantarell, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

nav li a:hover{
    color: #FE4C06;
}

#navclear{
    clear:both;
}
```

I am new to html5. Here i am facing problem with  height property.I want to make my my nav height auto i tried the same with above syntax but the ul part overflowed from nav.Means height:auto; not working . i cant fix the same by  nav ul {margin-top:0;}. Here my question is how to make nav height auto?

http://jsbin.com/alukej/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Why are you using `!height:35px`? Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: If you want the height to be auto, just remove `!height:35px;`, which shouldn't have the exclamation point anyway. If that doesn't do what you want, `height:auto;` isn't the problem. Instead, you should explain what you're trying to achieve. Height with CSS can be confusing sometimes, so it's likely working correctly.

Comment: i just removed !height:35px; but still have the same problem. i am using fire fox @thirtydot

Comment: Your question does not contain enough detail. It is not answerable. Nobody can answer it. All we can do it guess, because your question is unclear. Here's my guess: add `nav { overflow: hidden }`. You should improve your question. Try making a http://jsbin.com/ demo.

Comment: It will work if you change `</nav><p id="navclear" />` to `<p id="navclear"></p></nav>`. It's not good code though.

Comment: thirtydot thanks it's works fine. bad code? then how can i improve it?Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

As thirtydot commented, you had the `<p class="clear" />` in the wrong spot.  Here's revised code below:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Login</a></li> 
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</nav>
```

*I deleted all of your unnecessary code (you still had a lot of "!")*

- [jsBin Edit 1](http://jsbin.com/alukej/3/edit)

Another option is to use `nav li{ display: inline; }` instead of `nav li{ float:right; }` Code below:

- [jsBin Edit 2](http://jsbin.com/alukej/4/edit)

---

**ORIGINAL**

*Just to expand on thirtydot and Nathanael's comments.*

`!higher:35px` is the wrong syntactical usage of the exclamation point in CSS.  See here for an explanation on how to use it correctly:

- [How do you read !important in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369216/how-do-you-read-important-in-css)

With that said, it doesn't appear that you need `!important` in your CSS code.

Furthermore, you don't need your last line either, `height:auto;` because that is already the default behavior of the element's height property.  So, as far as any of us can tell right now, your final code simply needs to be:

- [jsFiddle.net Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g2gnS/)

HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

​CSS

```
nav{
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
}​
```

*If you are trying do achieve something different, please edit your question and explain it more clearly.  Sometimes pictures help with HTML questions.*