# How can I change text colors and styling in chardin.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Today one of my friend suggested me to see `chardin.js`,how it's look good.So I downloaded `.css,.js` file from [this](https://github.com/heelhook/chardin.js) link and also I did what they suggested.it's working fine.

But I want to play with styelings like,what's to change text color,at the end of line what's to use arrow.Exactly not this .

where can I find that function names.

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.chardinjs-helper-layer {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

Read [How do you read !important in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369216/how-do-you-read-important-in-css)