# How do I override the predefined classes in the bootstrap?

Tags: html

How do i override predefined bootstrap classes?
What are different ways to apply our own CSS on those bootstrap classes?

Comment: They are just css classes, override them the same way you would to override any other css class

Comment: Just use `!important` on your own CSS. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369216/how-do-you-read-important-in-css

Comment: Hi, it's just CSS so you have to take specificity into account: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Do ***not*** follow osdavison's comment, that is not the way to do it.

Comment: 1. Create your own stylesheet.  
2. Use the same names of the classes or id you want to override. You can get the name of the id or class by inspecting it (Right click on the element you want to override and choose Inspect from the option appears).  
3. Use !important" declaration as it takes precedence over the normal declaration.

Ex.  p { color: red !important; }

4. Load your custom stylesheet after the bootstrap stylesheet in your page as browser read css from top to bottom and property found in last for any element will override the above properties.

Answer (score 1):

Load a second css file into your page after you load bootstrap, which contains rules that are identically named to any classes, ids, or selectors that you want to override.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect it, find right class, override it or set an id on the element.